# The class cannot inherit from the AndroidViewModel, why?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I try create a new class that inherits from AndroidViewModel, like this

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

       public LoginViewModel() {}
...
```

But I get this message in the ide:

*There is no default constructor available in 'android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel'*

My happen this?

My graddle looks like this:

```
...
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
...
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add **super** call to **[AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) class** when inheriting from it. `AndroidViewModel` class contains [default constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel#public-constructors) having `Application` class as variable, so you should change your implementation as below :

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

   public LoginViewModel(Application application) {
       super(application);
       // Do rest of your stuff here ...
   }
...
```

---

Default implementation of `AndroidViewModel` class states that :

> `Application` context aware `ViewModel`.
>
> **Subclasses** must have a constructor which accepts `Application` as the
>   only parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`AndroidViewModel` has only one public constructor that takes an `Application` as parameter. You must call this from your constructor:

```
public LoginViewModel(Application app) {
    super(app);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel

Subclasses must have a constructor which accepts Application as the only parameter.